# Using do while inside of wordpress shortcode causes 500 error

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to encapsulate a do while loop inside of my custom php code. However, the code itself causes a 500 error. Is this due to a techincal aspect of $wpdb or wordpress's shortcode?

If I comment out the do and while loop the site runs fine. Even if the code does nothing to the $Num_Page value, the site still displays the 500 error

```
add_shortcode('num1', 'num_function');

function num_function() {

global $wpdb;

// this is the counter
$Num_Page = 0;

do {

// rest of code here

     } while ($Num_Page < 50);
}
```

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: _"Even if the code does nothing to the $Num_Page value"_ If the code does nothing to the $Num_Page value then you have an infinite loop which will probably time out and throw a 500.

Comment: Isnt the point of having a do {} to stop the infinite loop? Or does the do {} only display everything once $Num_Page is equal to the maximum value?

Comment: A `do{}while()` does the loop while the `while` condition is true. If `$Num_Page` is always less than 50, then the loop will never end.

Comment: `do { code } while (condition);` runs `code` over and over again as long as `condition` is true. So if you never change `$Num_Page` inside your loop, then your condition will always be true and the loop will never exit.

Comment: Thank you! It works flawlessly now